# What does the number of parallel lines in a relay symbol imply?

Tags: relay, schematics

Some relay cores are represented by two parallel lines and others by three. Does the number of parallel lines have any significance?

[image]

Saw this symbol in Tiny cad. What does three parallel lines in the picture imply?

Comment: A picture would help.

Comment: Here is some indication http://www.g3npf.co.uk/inductors.htm. It's for inductors though. But no standards mentioned.

Comment: Number of lines has no significance - artistic freedom prevails in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

It would indicate an inductor (the coil) wound around an iron core (as opposed to no lines indicating an air-wound inductor).

Comment: And the number of lines only says how many lines the designer of the relay symbol thought looked good.